# GTK+/GCC Crashing On Start

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk, mingw

I'm trying to learn how to use GTK in C.

I'm developing using Eclipse CDT.  I copied the following code from an examples website:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayUI()
{
GtkWidget* mainWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), 400, 300);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), "GTK Simple Example");
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);

gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(mainWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_widget_show_all(mainWindow);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

gboolean b = gtk_init_check(&argc, &argv);

if(b == 0) {
    puts("Failed to init");
    exit(0);
}

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

displayUI();

gtk_main();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Every time I try to run this program (or anything else involving GTK, Windows immediately displays a "InsertProgramNameHere.exe has crashed" message.

I have MinGW, MinSYS, PKG-CONFIG and MAKE all properly installed.  The program compiles fine... it just won't run.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found this error log.  There seems to be a dependency problem.

```
Faulting application TestRun.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x4f839a6a, faulting

module libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll, version 6.0.6002.18541, time stamp 0x4ec3e39f, exception 

code 0xc0000135, fault offset 0x0006f52f, process id 0x1674, application start time 

0x01cd16c174d3df90.
```

Comment: I think after gtk_init_check, gtk_init is redundant. I dunno if that's the crash cause though.

Comment: It is redundant.  I forgot to remove gtk_init().  The program crashes before ever even executing main though (tested it with a puts() at beginning) which is what is quite confusing.

Comment: Depending on the buffering behavior of stdout on windows (I dunno, I'm a unix guy), the crash may preclude the output getting to the console. Call fflush (stdout) right after or use fputs(s,stderr) to make sure.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this code compiles and runs fine under *nix?  I don't have the tools with me now.

Comment: Compiles and runs with gtk2, doesn't compile with gtk3.

Comment: It works fine on Linux.  @ghostsoldier23 Gtk+ may be aborting because of being unable to locate necessary modules.  How is it installed?  (I don't have Windows so I might not be able to help much, though.)

Comment: You might be able to get more detailed information about the crash by looking in the Windows error logs under Management Console (`Right-Click` on `My Computer` Choose `manage`.) Beyond that, I use Linux, so I don't know the exact way to get to the log of application errors. I would just find it by looking around at the different logs.

Comment: I just have the libraries in a directory inside of my workspace directory.  Eclipse includes the header files from there.  Should it be somewhere else?

Comment: I was able to find a relevant error log in the Windows Management Console.  See OP.

Answer (score 4):

> exception code 0xc0000135

That is STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.  Gtk+ has a large number of dependent DLLs.  Probably your best bet to get started is to use the [all-in-one bundle](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip) and copy the entire content of the bin directory in the archive to your program's EXE directory.  Crude but [the docs](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) are quite unapologetic about it:

> Many of the developer files are relatively irrelevant. If you intend to redistribute the GTK+ run-time, you need to figure out which files you can leave out yourself

Comment: The DLL "faulting" in the error message exists.  I'm not sure whether or not that would be what it think isn't found?

Comment: It is not a standard Windows error message, good odds that it comes out of mingw.  It is common to see the name of the file that caused the exception but not common to see what file was missing.  So you don't know exactly what DLL libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll needs.  Google "windows loader snaps" if you really want to drill it down.

Comment: I think the all-in-one bundle is what I have.  I can try again though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your GTK installation directory is in your PATH ?

Comment: The Windows PATH or the Eclipse PATH?

Comment: Depends on what you use to run the executable. If your run it from eclipse, then yes, from Eclipse. If you run it from a shell or by double-clicking on the file explorer, then the Windows PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to (MinGW, MinSYS and gtk-dev)'s bin folder in the environment variables.